# Angular Services, best practice

Tags: angular, service, angular5

I have 10 functions (that are all associated with Mobile Navigation) that are used in myFooterComponent.
Another myHeaderComponent needs to access 2 of those functions.

My options are:

1. Create a service and allow the 2 components to share all 10
   functions (even though 8 of which will only be used by 1 component).
2. Create a service and allow the 2 components to share just those 2
   necessary functions and keep the other 8 functions in
   myFooterComponent's ts file.
3. Just copy the 2 functions into the myHeaderComponent's ts file
   (duplicate the functions myHeaderComponent requires).

I feel like the 1st option would be best for clarity, to keep all the functions associated with Mobile Navigation together. Rather than the 2nd option where 2 of the functions will be in a different file and to look at all the Mobile Nav functions I'd have to go between the two files.
And the 3rd option just seems like bad practice.

So my question is which is the best option?

Answer (score -1):

I would go with first option, If all your functions are designed to provide service then, all should go at one place, except the functions that are used by only one components.

Comment: Is that not the 2nd option?
Are you saying that **only** the shared functions should be the service?